# Showing a time countdown progress bar

Tags: jquery, css

I came across this progress bar code on [this site](http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery/).

What I want to do is, have a 3 minute countdown and show how many minutes and seconds are left. So rather than displaying percentage I want to display time left.

I use the following code:

**JS**

```
progress(100, $('#progressBar')); // This is what the timer should update each second

function progress(percent, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + " minutes/seconds to go");
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #progressBar {
  width: 923px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
}
```

Comment: The percentage is ok I guess for visualisation. But the text must display how much time is left.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll need to change a bit this function :

- Use 3 parameters (`timeleft`, `timetotal`, `element`) instead of the 2 actual
- Use `setTimeout()` to refresh your progress bar every second
- Check `timeleft` to know if you **need** to refresh the progress bar

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element
        .find('div')
        .animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500)
        .html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(180, 180, $('#progressBar'));
```

Plus, you should add this CSS, to avoid your progress bar to overflow its container :

```
#progressBar div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(180, 180, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**[Tip]**

If you want your progress bar to smoothly and constantly decrease, use this code instead :

```
.animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, "linear")
```

Comment: So this makes it from 100% width down to 0%, what if i wanted to do it the otherway around, from 0 to 100?

Comment: go it, its was "var progressBarWidth = (timetotal-timeleft) * ($element.width()/timetotal);"

Comment: Hi @zessx, how to disable the progress bar from animate when the page is load?