# Show hh:mm:ss on this code? (progressBar)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I modificate the following example that shows me hh:mm:ss on the bar? 
check out this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Rudchyk/pen/qNOEGj) code .

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft/60) + ":"+ timeleft%60);
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(600, 600, $('#progressBar'));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `JS` with the following code .

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  //newcode 
  var hrs ;
  var mins = Math.floor(timeleft/60);
  var secs =  timeleft%60;
  if(mins.toString().length < 2){
    mins = "0" + mins;
  };
  if(secs.toString().length < 2){
    secs = "0" + secs;
  };
  if(!hrs){
    hrs = "00"
  };
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(hrs +":"+ mins+ " :" + secs);
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(600, 600, $('#progressBar'));
```

You can check out the code in this [Code pen link](https://codepen.io/Pushpraj13/pen/eYOrpyV)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as expected but I have 2 issues: 1) it think the time is not very exact on higher times. 2) it seems that the timer not working exactly if another tab is on focus on Chrome. Can maybe make some modifications about that?

Comment: Welcome .. I will check you code by tonight and get back to you with it .. Will you please do me a favor by accepting an answer ? @andyk.

Comment: It seems that every minute the time is async for +1 sec. and that sums it up on higher times so that is wrong :) have you have time to look into it? :)

Comment: Sorry man , yesterday was my project submission . Today i will look at it by sure .. @andyK

Comment: Am really sorry dude . Actually i m in my deadline . Got to finish word as there are few changes , @AndyK. Promising to solve your issue within 1 hour . Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: I have updated the code in code pen link , Kindly go through it . It is working proper in my crome , ping me if you face any problem . Sorry for delay . @AndyK.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the method to include hours and reformat it

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(format(timeleft));
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};
function pad(i) {
 return i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
}
function format(timeInSecs){
 const hours = parseInt(timeInSecs / 3600,10);
 timeInSecs %= 3600;
 const mins = parseInt(timeInSecs / 60,10);
 const secs = parseInt(timeInSecs % 60,10);
 return pad(hours) + ":" + pad(mins) + ":" + pad(secs);
}
progress(600, 600, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Do not take in account */
html{padding-top:30px}a.solink{position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;text-align:center;background:#f3f5f6;color:#cfd6d9;border:1px solid #cfd6d9;line-height:30px;text-decoration:none;transition:all .3s;z-index:999}a.solink::first-letter{text-transform:capitalize}a.solink:hover{color:#428bca}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24530908/1238019" class="solink" target="_blank">Div CSS Transition Direction</a>
```