# React js: Activating progressbar countdown after button click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to activate a progressbar countdown after I push abutton. So the button will be disabled for 90 seconds. After the progressbar arrived to 90, the button will be active again.
How to do that?

[image: bar]

Below is what I was able to achieve so far:

**js:**

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
    }

    updateRequest() {
        const url =
            'html request for API';
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url, fetchConfig)
            .then((jsonObject) => {
                // fetching data
              })
            });
        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact>
                    <div class="progress-circle p0">
                        <span>0%</span>
                        <div class="left-half-clipper">
                            <div class="first50-bar" />
                            <div class="value-bar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-next-request" onClick={() => this.updateRequest()}>
                        Time to Next API Request
                    </button>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I came across the [following source](https://www.codespeedy.com/javascript-countdown-timer-with-progress-bar/) but was not able to figure out how to implement it yet.

2) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530908/showing-a-time-countdown-progress-bar) is a good source too. However I am not sure about the approach it was taken. Despite that, I was able thanks to that post to set the `button` call. I can confirm that the `button` is correctly functioning and sending the request.

3) In addition this is another good source, although it is using `jquery`. I am not very familiar with `jquery` but this could be a good approach. However, I would prefer not to mix too many things.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout/setInterval are not 100% accurate. The best way to achieve this would be to store the `new Date()` on button click, and then use setInterval to update the progress.

The solution would look like this:

```js
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countdownInterval = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.buttonClickedAt) return;
            const date = new Date();
            const diff = Math.floor((date.getTime() - this.state.buttonClickedAt.getTime()) / 1000);

            if (diff < 90) {
                this.setState({
                    progress: diff,
                    buttonEnabled: false,
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    progress: 0,
                    buttonClickedAt: null,
                    buttonEnabled: true,
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
    }

    updateRequest() {
        const url =
            'html request for API';
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url, fetchConfig)
            .then((jsonObject) => {
                // fetching data
              })
            });
        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact>
                    <div class="progress-circle p0">
                        <span>{this.state.progress}%</span>
                        <div class="left-half-clipper">
                            <div class="first50-bar" />
                            <div class="value-bar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-next-request" onClick={() => this.updateRequest()}>
                        Time to Next API Request
                    </button>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect :) that works! Thank you very much for your help!